# Transport equation in 1D (python)

Tags: python, differential-equations

I'm trying to write a python program to solve the convection equation in 1D using the finite differences method (upwind scheme). The problem is as follows:

Here's what I've attempted

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

def u0(x):
    if (0.4 <= x <= 0.5):
        y = 10*(x - 0.4)
    elif (0.5 <= x <= 0.6):
        y = 10*(0.6 - x)
    else:
        y = 0
    return y

print('Choix de la vitesse de transport c : ')
c = float(input('c = '))

def solex(x, t):
    return u0(x - c*t)

print('Choix de pas h : ')
h = float(input('h = '))

print('Choix du pas dt et du temps final T : ')
dt = float(input('dt = '))
T = float(input('T = '))

# Maillage

N = int((1/h) - 1)
x = linspace(0, 1, N + 2)
M = int((T/dt) - 1)
t = linspace(0, T, M + 2)

# Itération

U1 = zeros(N)
U2 = zeros(N)
sol = zeros((N, M + 2))

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    U1[i - 1] = u0(x[i])

sol[:, 0] = U1

for j in range(1, size(t)):
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        U2[i] = U1[i] - c*(dt/h)*(U1[i] - U1[i - 1])
    sol[:, j] = U2
    U1 = U2
```

It doesn't seem to work and I don't know why

Comment: Can you tell us what you get? and what you desire?

Comment: I got a vector full of zeros, and I knew I had to get a vector from 0 to 1 with step 0,1. Anyway, I think I've solved it. I think the problem was with the indentation in the i for-loop inside the j for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Though you said you already solved your problem, I would still like to suggest some general improvements:

1. wildcard imports like `from numpy import *` are considered bad practice, better use `import numpy as np` and refer to the necessary functions as `np.linspace` etc.
2. the power of `numpy` comes from vectorization, so try to replace as much `for`-loops as possible by vectorized operations.
3. at least from what you showed us, the variables `U1` and `U2` are not really necessary.
4. using `input` for every single parameter might be overkill

The following code includes my suggested improvements. Note how I replaced your `u0` with a vectorized version using `np.piecewise` and replaced several `for`-loops. I also added a visualisation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def u0(x):
    y= np.piecewise(
        x,
        [(0.4 <= x)&(x <= 0.5),  (0.5 <= x)&(x<= 0.6)     ],
        [lambda x: 10*(x - 0.4), lambda x: 10*(0.6 - x), 0])
    return y

c = 0.9
h = 0.01
dt = 0.01
T = 2

N = int(np.ceil(1/h))
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
M = int(np.ceil(T/dt))
t = np.linspace(0, T, M)

#solve with upwind scheme
sol = np.zeros((N, M))
sol[:,0] = u0(x)
#you could add boundary values here by setting
#sol[0,:] = <your_boundary_data>
for i in range(1,len(t)):
    sol[1:,i] = sol[1:,i-1] - c*(dt/h)*(sol[1:,i-1] - sol[:-1,i-1])

#Visualization
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('t')

T, X = np.meshgrid(t, x)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, T, sol)
```